# Нужна ли запятая при уточнении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Сегодня вышел уже юбилейный(,) пятый выпуск шоу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая нужна, это пояснительные члены предложения. Можно вставить: а именно